# Clear visual studio 2013 "Document well"

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have a user control opened in design mode. When I try to close this tab, visual studio 2013 crashes. If I open the project again, the user control tab is still there, I can't ever close it.

So, were in hell does visual studio save this "opened documents" per project, so I can delete this entry?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, It was simple. Delete the .suo file.